# Regex Quantifier for exactly one

Tags: python, regex

I have few patterns like:

```
orange.*
*.key.*
jug.*.key
```

Here, by `*` - I mean exactly one word.

So, the pattern `*.key.*` should match the string `bar.key.door` (one word on each side) but **not** `fruit.bar.key.door` (two words before `key`).

How do i write a regex pattern for this in Python?

Comment: Which Regex is this? * means 0 or more occurrences and not exactly one occurrence.

Comment: You could try this [`^\w+\.key\.\w+$`](https://regex101.com/r/FasUKz/2)

Comment: You could try [`^[^.]+\.key\.[^.]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/8WvEPt/1)

Comment: `orange.*` as a regex is `orange` followed by zero or more characters. `orange.*` as a *shell pattern* is the string `orange.` followed by zero or more characters. Which are you actually asking about?

Comment: @AmanChhabra it is the topic exchange pattern in RabbitMQ

Comment: `*.key.*` is not even a valid regular expression, unless you are using a regular-expression engine that special-cases an initial `*` as a literal `*`. It *is*, however, a valid shell pattern, which matches any string that contains the 5-character sequence `.key.` somewhere in the string.

Comment: @chepner The OP didn't mean `orange.*` is a regular expression.  They meant that they have strings that look like `orange.<something>`, and they wanted to create a regular expression to match that only when `<something>` was a single word.

Comment: Ah, I see the confusion, `*.key.*` is a [rabbitmq binding key](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-python.html). It is most definitely *not* a regular expression. You should [edit] your question to reflect that, and then edit the tags to get rid of `regex`.

Comment: For example, the pattern "jug.*.key" should match only those strings having a single word between jug. and .key. like, "jug.table.key", but not" jug.table.door.key"

Comment: @shweta ok cool. There are lot of options to implement this. See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50931974/1262248

Answer (score 1):

One way you could match that pattern is to use anchors to assert the start `^` and the end `$` of the line and match match the unknown part by using `^[^.]+` (a negated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)) or use `\w+` to match one or more word characters.

For example:

[`^[^.]+\.key\.[^.]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/8WvEPt/1/)

```
import re
p = re.compile('^[^.]+\.key\.[^.]+$')
m = p.match('bar.key.door')
print (m.group())
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/FYYMY45308)

Some options for your other patterns could be: [`^orange\.\w+$`](https://regex101.com/r/CcD9Yt/1) and [`^jug\.[^.]+\.key$`](https://regex101.com/r/JPHsJg/1)

Comment: What is a word character? Is it a word or a char?

Comment: @Timo a word character is `\w` See https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to implement it:

```
Option 1: ^[\w]+\.key\.[\w]+$
Option 2: ^[[:word:]]+\.key\.[[:word:]]+$
Option 3: ^[^.]+\.key\.[^.]+$
Option 4: ^[A-Za-z]+\.key\.[A-Za-z]+$
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`.` matches any character except a newline. to match the literal `.` it needs to be escaped, like `\.`.

> `*` - means exactly 1 word

`*` is another regex character meaning match 0 or more repetitions of the previous character group. `\w+` would match a word. a single *word* would imply the string terminates (before or after), so it can be checked for using `^` or `$`.

check out the [official re library documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html) for more info. It has worked examples and is a very good tutorial for learning regex.

so, the 3 regex patterns would be:

```
p1 = r'orange\.\w+$'
p2 = r'^\w+\.key\.\w+$'
p3 = r'^jug\.\w+\.key$'
```